# Showing that triangles in $\mathbb{Z}$ are thin

Tags: group-theory, geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

If we let $\mathbb{Z}$ be generated by $\{3,5\}$ then I have a question which asks me to show that geodesic triangles are $k$-thin and to find a minimum bound on $k$. I have been thinking about this for a while but I am not sure how to prove this (I am not too happy about proving things are $k$-thin in general hence my other questions)

I know that the Cayley graph "looks like" a line with the vertices for all the integers and that say on the top we have lines going from $x$ to $x+3$ and on the bottom that we have lines going from $x$ to $x+5$.

Now I am confused as how to show that any triangle is $k$-thin? I am slightly confused as to what a geodesic triangle actually looks like here?

> Idea If I take a geodesic triangle between the points say $0,3-2$ then two of these sides have length $1$ and the other has length $2$ (the side connecting $-2$ to $0$ as we have to go via $-5$ then this triangle is $1$-thin but I have no idea how to generalise this argument to all geodesic triangle

I know that this type of question is poorly suited here (as I can't draw pictures) but some help with this would be great.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Note that a geodesic word consists mainly of $5$s (or $-5$s) and has at most $4$ occurrences of $3$ or $-3$. So in a triangle with vertices $a,b,c$ and $a \le b \le c$, a geodesic path from $a$ to $c$ with pass $b$ at a bounded distance away and will stay a bounded distance from the concatenation of any geodesic paths from $a$ to $b$ and from $b$ to $c$. So, it is not hard to see that geodesic triangles are thin. But I would not want to try and calculate the smallest possible $k$, so I don't envy you that!

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks. Could you explain your first line a bit please?

Comment: In any word, you can replace $5$ $3$s by $3$ $5$s, and so a word containing $5$ or more $3$s cannot be geodesic.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ah yes of course, thanks for the help! :) If you wish to post as an answer I would gladly accept